# Listing a file in UNIX and then using loop

Tags: bash, unix

I have a list of directory names in a file called list. For each name in the list I need to go that directory and check for a pattern of files and then move them to same directory name but in another path. I have done this. Here I am listing 'list1' and then for each name in list1 I am going that directory under /a/b/c/d and searching for pattern of file with No and moving them to same directory name under /a/b/c/r.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/a/home/mydir/list1
for f in $list1
do
cd /a/b/c/d/$f
find . -type f -name "*No*" -exec mv {} /a/b/c/r/$f. \;
done
```

I am getting following output:

> ./read.sh: line 5: cd: /a/b/c/d//u/home/mydir/list1: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
>   ./read.sh: line 6: cd: /a/b/c/d//u/home/mydir/list1: A parameter must be a directory.
>   mv: /a/b/c/d//u/home/mydir/list1.: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
>   mv: /a/b/c/d//u/home/mydir/list1.: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
>   mv: /a/b/c/d//u/home/mydir/list1.: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
>   mv: /a/b/c/d//u/home/mydir/list1.: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't even see a question mark...

Answer (score 1):

You are addressing `$list1` but that's not a variable that has been assigned a value previously. Also you have a variable FILES that is unused, where does that come in?

Try something along the lines:

```
while read filename ; do
    cd /a/b/c/d/$filename
    find . -type f ... # etcetera
done < /a/home/mydir/list1
```

This will read lines from `/a/home/mydir/list1` and per iteration assign what's read to `$filename`. This `$filename` is used inside the loop to do whatever you should do with it.

Comment: Thank you. This loop worked. But now I have got a different problem. the files that needs to be moved don't have permission. So after finding the files with '*No*' pattern I need to change the permission and then move. Is it possible to execute 2 commands after 'find' command?

Comment: Just process the files one by one in your script, make a loop inside your loop: `for f in $(find -type f ...); do ... ; done`. In the `for` loop you can do your `chmod` and `mv` commands.